# converting equation from radians to degrees with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, math, trigonometry

I am building a calculator app and my client needs the ability to change from radians to degrees. I have read that by multiplying the argument of trigonometric functions by 180/pi you can convert radians to degrees. for my calculator app I am basically parsing a string and passing it to the math.js API. so my method of trying to convert the equation to degrees from radians is

the web app is here http://147.182.241.143:82/Calculator

```js
if(this.calc_mode == 'deg'){
    result = result.split('cos(').join('cos((180/pi) * ').split('sin(').join('sin((180/pi) * ')
}
```

so this `5(sin(3)-cos(pi*15))/4` gets turned into this `5(sin((180/pi) * 3)-cos((180/pi) * pi*15))/4`

what am i missing in order to convert over to degrees.

EDIT:

so now I am trying to iterate through the equation and insert `(180 / pi)` right after each number.

```js
var res = result.replace(/\D/g, " ");
var split = res.split('');
var next_char_numeric = this.is_numeric(split[i +1])
for(var i = 0; i < split.length; i++){
    if(this.is_numeric(split[i]) && next_char_numeric == false){  

            console.log('false')
            var res = res.insert(i, "(180/pi)")
            console.log(res);
            i + 8;
    }
}
console.log(res)

is_numeric(str){
    return /^\d+$/.test(str);
}

String.prototype.insert = function(index, string) {
  if (index > 0) {
    return this.substring(0, index) + string + this.substr(index);
  }
  return string + this;
};
```

this fails horribly as all I want to do is multiply each operand by (180 / pi) how can I do this programmatically through js

Comment: Doesn't `cos()` and `sin()` take their arguments in radians?

Comment: i dont really know I have a basic understanding of this

Comment: You can display angles any way you want, degrees or radians, but when you apply trig functions to these angles you need to supply the angles in radians.